# Python Regex Failure....?

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying various solutions all yesterday, before I hung it up and went to bed.   After coming back today and taking another look at it... I still cannot understand what is wrong with my regex statement.

I am trying to search my inventory based on a simple name and return an item index and the amount of that item that I have.

for instance, in my inventory instead of knife I could have bloody_knife[9] at the 0 index and the script should return 9, and 0, based on the query of knife.

**The code:**

```
import re

inventory = ["knife", "bottle[1]", "rope", "flashlight"]


def search_inventory(item):
    numbered_item = '.*' + item + '\[([0-9]*)\].*'
    print(numbered_item)                   #create regex statement
    regex_num_item = re.compile(numbered_item)
    print(regex_num_item)                  #compiled regex statement
    for x in item:
        match1 = regex_num_item.match(x)   #regex match....
        print(match1)                      #seems to be producing nothing.
        if match1:                         #since it produces nothing the code fails.
            num_item = match1.group()
            count = match1.group(1)
            print(count)
            index = inventory.index(num_item)
        else:                              #eventually this part will expand to include "item not in inventory"
            print("code is wrong")
        return count, index

num_of_item, item_index = search_inventory("knife")
print(num_of_item)
print(item_index)
```

**The output:**

```
.*knife\[([0-9]*)\].*
re.compile('.*knife.*\\[([0-9]*)\\].*')
None
code is wrong
```

One thing that I cannot seem to settle well with is when python takes the code in my `numbered_item` variable and uses it in the `re.compile()` function.  why is it adding additional escapes when I already have the necessary `[]` escaped.

Has anyone run into something like this before?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to search for an item in my inventory based on a simple name and return a item index and the amount of that item.

Comment: Can you reduce the code to *exactly* the problem you're having? From a rough guess, this could be one or more lines with only a regex and a (fixed) input string, together with expected output and actual output. Right now, we'd have to go through your whole function definition, which seems unnecessary for a regex problem.

Comment: "why is it adding additional escapes when I already have the necessary [] escaped": at a guess, you're only *seeing* additional escapes. To print an explicit backslash, Python prefixes such a backslash with a backslash (`'\n'` and `'\\n'` are two different beasts, and Python will therefore show them differently). So if you mean the double backslashes in `'.*knife.*\\[([0-9]*)\\].*'`: those are still single backslashes.

Comment: Ill see what I can do to reduce the code, at the moment the biggest problem is that, while I believe my regex to be correct match1 and match2 do not produce any output.

Comment: Thank you for the description, it has cleared that portion up for me.

Comment: I have stripped it down to the bare minimum, and added some additional comments.

Comment: I don't understand why you are even using regex here. You're not matching anything unusual a simple `for x in inventory: if item in x` would work. Even then you should be storing these items as keys in a dict with the value being the count.

Comment: Even though I just completed my lesson on dicts, I didn't think to use one... that definitely improves the code a lot! The reason why I was looking to use regex, is if i needed to search the inventory for a knife(as an example) and didn't have a "knife" item, but did have a "bloody_knife" item.  I wanted both to count.  Thank you. p.s. - sorry for the beginner mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
 for x in item:
```

That is looking at "for every character in your item `knife`". So your regex was running on `k`, then `n`, and so on. Your regex won't want that of course. If you still wanted to "see it", add a print x:

```
for x in item:
        print x                            #add this line
        match1 = regex_num_item.match(x)   #regex match....
        print(match1)                      #seems to be producing nothing.
```

You'll see that it will print each letter of the item. That's what you're matching against in your `match1 = regex_num_item.match(x)` so obiously it won't work.
You want to iterate over the `inventory`.

So you want:

```
 for x in inventory:    #meaning, for every item in inventory
```

---

Is the `index` important to you? Because you can change the inventory into a dictionary and you don't have to use regex:

```
inventory = {'knife':8, 'bottle':1, 'rope':1, 'flashlight':0, 'bloody_knife':1}
```

And then, if you wanted to find every item that has the word `knife` and how many you have of it:

```
for item in inventory:
    if "knife" in item:
        itemcount = inventory[item]           #in a dictionary, we get the 'value' of the key this way
        print "Item Name: " + item + "Count: " + str(itemcount)
```

Output:

```
Item Name: bloody_knife, Count: 1
Item Name: knife, Count: 8
```

Comment: I feel rather stupid... although I still don't understand why it wouldn't match against item.  Thank you, it seems the solution was in the place that I wasn't looking.

Comment: @Requiemsallure I've edited my answer. In your `for x in item`, that means "for every character in item" because `item` = `knife` right?

Comment: This is an excellent answer!  The index will be important because it will allow me to mix it with a replace function.  As an example if you have a `bottle[4]` or `bottle:4` in the inventory and you want to gather water, I would use the replace definition to replace one bottle in the inventory using the `inventory.remove(index)` and then `inventory.insert(index, "bottle[3]")`  and then add `inventory.append("bottle(water)[1]")` so whether i am searching for a item or whether the code is parsing for an item to replace. I wanted the definition to be flexible.

Comment: @Requiemsallure, you will still be able to do that in a dictionary. If you wanted to remove one bottle from the inventory, you would do `inventory['bottle'] -= 1`, which is short for `inventory['bottle'] = inventory['bottle'] - 1`, and obviously `inventory['bottle']` refers to the value (quantity) of the key 'bottle'. Learn more about dictionaries man, they are powerful and very important.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into this right away!